# is there a technique to identify hash algorithm/encoding thats being used?

Tags: encoding, hash, cryptography

For example, take this hash or encoding string:

`[<åæ0®(k±¥Ò,X±}@ãqã Î(KmV`

Is it possible to identify the hasing or encoding algorithm used to generate this string using some kind of algorithm?

Comment: This is not encoded. If you want a specific hash analysed then you need to show it completely. Since hash outputs are binary you need to use an encoding like base64 or hex. You lose bytes by simply copying the output as text. But StackOverflow or any other site on the StackExchange for that matter is not the place to ask such questions. How such hashes can be identified without a specific example on the other hand is a really profound question, but is not a good fit for SO. [crypto.se] is a better fit for this type of question, but I think it will be too broad and dismissed really fast.

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3989/how-to-determine-what-type-of-encoding-encryption-has-been-used

Comment: It works best if you already have some candidates, but then you can check yourself. If you have some of them like RIPEMD-160 and SHA1 for 160-bit output, you may ask something like *How can the two be distinguised based on the hashes?* and the answer will be almost certainly *you can't*.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Analyzing a piece of code is explicitly off topic on crypto... (they may just tell the OP that a good crypto hash function would return results indistinguishable from random and that you can only brute force using the input or look up the value in rainbow tables)...

Answer (score 0):

1. Hash functions produce a result of a given size, so a 256 bit hash output must have been produced by a hash that produces at least 256 bits.  That does not work the other way, since a longer output might be truncated before use -- the 256 bits may be taken from a 512 bit hash output.  Beyond that it is basically a matter of trial and error.
2. Cyphers are designed to produce random-appearing output.  Hence, the output from good cyphers appears random and you should not be able to tell which cypher was used to produce this particular random-appearing output.
3. The presence of IVs, nonces etc. and the cyphertext length might tell you something about what mode was used, and the block size for a block cypher.